sigma.js @sigma/edge-curve How to use webgl rendering
The default is 2D rendering. When renderEdgeLabels:true is used, it will freeze when the amount of data is large. How to use webgl to render edgeLabels
const renderer = new Sigma(
      graph,
      sigmaRef.value as HTMLDivElement,
      {
        defaultEdgeType: "straight",
        renderEdgeLabels: true, // 默认展示edge label就会卡顿
        nodeProgramClasses: {
          image: NodeImageProgram
        },
        edgeProgramClasses: {
          straight: EdgeArrowProgram,
          curved: EdgeCurveProgram,
        }
      }
  );

I tried searching on Google but couldn't find a solution.
